# How do I convert a c# two-dimensional array to a JSON object?

Tags: c#, javascript, json

If I have a two-dimensional array in C# - how can I convert it into a JSON string that contains a two dimensional array?

eg.

```
int[,] numbers = new int[8,4];
JavaScriptSerializer js = new JavaScriptSerializer();
string json = js.Serialize(numbers);
```

gives a flat one-dimensional array in a JSON object. The [Microsoft documentation states](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.script.serialization.javascriptserializer?view=netframework-4.8#mapping-between-managed-types-and-json):

*'A multidimensional array is serialized as a one-dimensional array, and you should use it as a flat array.'*

Comment: Just for fun, I'll add that [Newtonsoft's Json.NET](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json) doesn't have this serialization issue with two+-dimensional arrays and, to cover a popular use case in 2021, ASP.NET Core even [provides a way to switch over](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.dependencyinjection.newtonsoftjsonmvcbuilderextensions.addnewtonsoftjson?view=aspnetcore-5.0)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can use a jagged array instead of a two-dimensional array, which is defined like:

```
int[][] numbers = new int[8][];

for (int i = 0; i <= 7; i++) {
   numbers[i] = new int[4];
   for (int j = 0; j <= 3; j++) {
      numbers[i][j] =i*j;
   }
}
```

The JavascriptSerializer will then serialise this into the form [[#,#,#,#],[#,#,#,#],etc...]