# How To parse a multidimensional array to a JSON object?

Tags: javascript, .net, asp.net-mvc, json

I am working over an MVC website where I want to load data from the server asynchronously
I have following route, controller and model in place

```
routes.MapRoute("Search", "Student/{class}/{min}", new { controller = "Student", action = "Search", class = UrlParameter.Optional,min=  UrlParameter.Optional });
```

`Controller:`

```
    public JsonResult GetClassPosts(string class, int min)
    {
        var blgObj = new Student();
        string[,] classPosts = blgObj.GetClassPosts(class, min);
        ViewData["ClassPosts"] = class;
        ViewData["ClassPosts"] = classPosts;
            //How To parse a multidimensional array to a JSON object?
        return Json(classPosts, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

`Model:`

```
internal string[,] GetClassPosts(string class, int min)
    {    …
        var results = new string[10, 5];
        try
        {
            SqlDataReader sqlRdr = Shared.ORC(sqlCon, sqlCom);
            for (int i = 0; i < results.Length - 1 && sqlRdr.Read(); i++)
            { … }
        } …
        return results;
    }
```

And I have separate `.js` in which I am trying to write my function as:

```
$.ajax({
url: '@Url.Action("student", " GetClassPosts ")',
type: "GET",
success: function (result) {
    $("#somediv").append(....;
});
```

Now as it’s obvious that I am not returning a valid JSON object from the controller and I don’t know how to do it can anyone please help me with this?

Comment: A double array doesn't turn in to `result.FirstName` & `result.LastName`--I assume this was an attempt at making a `Dictionary<String,String>`?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I convert a c# two-dimensional array to a JSON object?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1291076/how-do-i-convert-a-c-sharp-two-dimensional-array-to-a-json-object)

Comment: @Brad Christie apologies, just added that as an example, i would just be passing string from the array in `.append`