# How to pass a C# array to a JavaScript array

Tags: c#, javascript, arrays

I am trying to pass my C# array to the JavaScript behind, I've managed to pass a integer to the code behind but when I try to pass the array, it only shows: var rawData = System.Int32[,];

This is what I have tried so far:

JavaScript

```
var rawData = <%=this.array2D%>;
```

C#

```
public int[,] array2D;

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    array2D = new int[,] { { 700, 0 }, { 300, 1 }, { 500, 2 }, { 700, 3 }, { 400, 4} };
}
```

Is what I want to achieve possible and if so, any suggestions to have I can make it work? Cheers.

Comment: You need to serialize the array into json or something. Json is an easy and fast way to do it.

Comment: Thanks, I may know a way how I can make that work, thanks!:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using Json.Net:

```
string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(array2D);
```

Answer (score 0):

You would first need to serialize your C# object to [json](http://json.org/). 
You can use something like [json.net](http://james.newtonking.com/json) to achieve this. Once on the client side in the javascript you need to parse the json to convert it into javascript.  You can have a look at a javascript library like [json2](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js) to do this.

Answer (score 0):

You can try tu use a js serializer on the view 
`<%@ Import Namespace="System.Web.Script.Serialization" %>`
var rawData = `<%=new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(this.array2D) %>`

Comment: The `JavaScriptSerializer` will convert the multi-dimensional array into a simple array like `[700,0,300,1,500,2,700,3,400,4]`. You may better use Json.Net or use jagged arrays as in [this SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1291076/how-do-i-convert-a-c-sharp-two-dimensional-array-to-a-json-object)