# Serialize and Deserialize Multidimensional Array to JSON

Tags: c#, json, javascriptserializer

I am using the built-in library `JavaScriptSerializer` to serialize and deserialize a multidimensional array.

It is stated in the MSDN that `A multidimensional array is serialized as a one-dimensional array, and you should use it as a flat array.`

I have tried to deserialize it, but kept getting `Unable to cast object of type 'System.Double[]' to type 'System.Double[,,]'.`

```
double[, ,] y = serializer.Deserialize<double[, ,]>(jsonMatrix);
```

Does this mean that i have re-construct it back manually ? If so, any solutions.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I convert a c# two-dimensional array to a JSON object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1291076/how-do-i-convert-a-c-sharp-two-dimensional-array-to-a-json-object)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If its serializes multi dimension array into flat array then you won't be able to de-serialize it back into multi dimension array.

Have a look at this thread, one of the solution uses Json.net to serialize and de-serialize multi dimension array.

[How to deseralize json object that contains multidimensional array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13469765/how-to-deseralize-json-object-that-contains-multidimensional-array)